# Use PuTTY as a local terminal emulator?

Tags: windows, cygwin, terminal, putty

Currently, I use PuTTY for SSHing into my linux server and Cygwin for local development when working on my Windows machine. Sadly, the terminal emulator that comes with Cygwin doesn't approach the quality of the excellent terminal emulator that comes with PuTTY. And it occurs to me that there really shouldn't be any conceptual difference between connecting PuTTY to a remote server over SSH and using PuTTY locally as a Windows shell to interface with the Cygwin system... but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this for the life of me. Is it possible to use PuTTY this way? If so, how?

Comment: Cygwin doesn't come with **any** terminal emulator.  That is to say, the default "Cygwin Bash Shell" link it adds to your Start menu uses Windows' own console, not anything of its own.

Comment: Have you tried ConEmu? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/1405560

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at [PuTTyCyg](http://code.google.com/p/puttycyg/).

Also I like to use MinTTY available through the Cygwin installer...

Comment: +1: MinTTY *is* PuTTY, just with the network and serial port comms stuff stripped out, making it only suitable as a local terminal program, like xterm on X systems.

Comment: Just as an FYI for other readers - this has not been maintained since 2011. It is no longer an active project

Comment: @Ascalonian Right, I no longer use PuTTYcyg myself, I recommend [mintty](https://mintty.github.io/) which I believe is now the default terminal in Cygwin. It is also available for MSYS1 and MSYS2 of MinGW/MinGW-w64. As mentioned above, mintty is basically a minimalistic fork of putty..

Comment: Also worth noting that mintty now only supports WSL 2, so if you're stuck on a corporate machine that doesn't allow the Windows Insider program and you're still on WSL 1, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose if you somehow managed to install and start an ssh server on your local cygwin environment, putty should be able to connect to localhost

Answer (score 1):

PuTTY lets you connect to servers with ssh. Have you tried running an `sshd` on your Cygwin, and connecting to localhost with PuTTY ?