# console2 - how to make it fullscreen?

Tags: console2

Is there any way to make console2 go fullscreen? I edit settings and increase window and buffer size but when I restart settings are reset to 63 rows in window size.

Comment: Not sure, it can be an exact answer to the question, but I am an author of another console emulator. One of long feature list - is maximized and fullscreen modes. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/1405560

Comment: @Maximus: I switched to ConEmu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK I managed to do it on win7 but still no luck on XP. This is how I did it.

- In *Settings→Behavior*, check the *Initial position* checkbox and left the *X* and *Y* as default `0`
- Restart console
- After restart, resize window dragging the borders to fill whole screen
- Restart again
- In *Settings→Appearance→More* uncheck *Caption* and *Border*

I don't know why just entering *rows* and *columns* doesn't work. One has to resize the window and restart.

On my screen with this font it is 62 rows (with space left for tabs on bottom) and 238 columns. I have 24" monitor. I set font to be Consolas size 11.

Answer (score 26):

I've found that the maximise button is disabled, but you can get around it by setting Run option of the executable's shortcut to Maximised.

[image: Shortcut Settings]

Better yet you can hide the window title bar in Console2's settings (Appearance > More... > Caption).

[image: Console2 Settings]

Here's the final result:

[image: Final Result]

Comment: this works great, however if you set up a global hotkey to switch to the console, it resizes back down.. cant find a fix. Did you have this issue?

Comment: Indeed, I have found that the window will resize under certain conditions/action but haven't found a fix either... I'm able to live with it by just avoiding the pitfalls.

Comment: When I start i maximized, then it goes beyond my task-manager. So if I write full screen of code, then I'll never be able to see the lowest 5 lines (due to the taskbar covering it). Therefor I voted Piotr Perak's answer up. But this is neat as well.

Comment: By the way... If someone else (like me) hide the menu, and don't know how to enable it again, then go to the folder where Console2.exe is located, open then file: console.xml and set show_menu to be = 1.

Comment: @Zeth alternatively, you can enable menu bar, 
by clicking "ctrl+s", then in "Appearance > More", check "Show Menu" in controls

Answer (score 20):

So, I've found this fork of Console2 which is amazingly better, it's called **ConsoleZ**:

https://github.com/cbucher/console/wiki/Downloads

Besides the maximization, it provides find in tabs, fullscreen mode and split tabs. Totally worth to check it out, IMHO.

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention, you can just download and replace the binaries, and all your configurations will be kept, as far as I've perceived.

[]'s

Comment: Currently I am using http://gooseberrycreative.com/cmder/. I will check ConsoleZ though. Thanks.

Comment: what u mean by replace the binary? replace the console2 binary with consolez binary?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the number of rows to change tab settings.
Click "Edit"->"Setting"->"Tabs" and click "Add" button. Then, the new entry which name is "Console" appears in the tab name list. In the main tab menu on the bottom, input these two parameters in the fields.

- Title: Cygwin
- Shell: C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -i

At last, move up the "Cygwin" entry to the top and restart console2. Now you can change the number of rows.

The detail how to configure tab settings is here.
https://openshift.redhat.com/community/blogs/upgrade-cygwin-to-console2-and-improve-the-productivity-of-openshifts-rhc-client-tools-on-wind

Answer (score 1):

In order to make Console2 have the desired window size (even when opening a new tab which generally causes the entire app's window to resize to smaller), do the following:

1. View -> Console Window
2. In the console window that pops up, right-click its title bar and select Properties
3. Set the window width/height and buffer sizes as you like and click OK

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I founded a small program called, [sizer 3.34](http://www.brianapps.net/sizer/), that configure the window size of every program window you have.

When installed, it apears at the popup menu, when you click with the secundary mouse button at the top bar of a window. It allows you to config the three size profiles it has, and to add one, or more, if you want.

I think is a good solution for this issue (and for another programms that would have the same problem).

Reggards.