# Vim on Cygwin and MinGW

Tags: windows, vim, cygwin, mingw

I have tried to use Vim both on Cygwin and MinGW but many times the characters behave in an unpredictable manner (backspace is not deleting, cannot have a semicolumn, and so on...). I am wondering if this is related to those systems or if it could be a problem of my own system/settings (e.g I need to adjust some settings, define the character encoding, etc.). I am on windows 7 64bit

Thank you

Comment: The Cygwin CMD emulator has a known problem with Vim.  Seems to be a redraw problem. Apparently fixing it would break execution of some exes that Cygwin depends on. Many users choose to use another terminal emulator. I find that paging down and back up fixes the redraw but sometimes I have to exit Vim and relaunch.

Comment: Could you suggest any other terminal emulator where vim works properly? thank you

Comment: By the way, there's a native version of vim (both in graphical and console version) that works perfectly fine under Windows, if you don't need it to work with "fake UNIX" paths it may be a solution.

Comment: @mottalrd Added terminal options as an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a better Windows Console Window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60950/is-there-a-better-windows-console-window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cygwin CMD emulator has a known problem with Vim. Seems to be a redraw problem. Apparently fixing it would break execution of some exes that Cygwin depends on. Many users choose to use another terminal emulator. I find that paging down and back up fixes the redraw but sometimes I have to exit Vim and relaunch.

PuTTYcyg is a patched version of PuTTY that, in addition to telnet, rlogin, ssh, and serial connections, can also be used as a local Cygwin terminal instead of the Windows console or xterm. See README.txt on the PuTTYcyg site for more information.

To use rxvt:
 @echo off
 C:
 chdir C:\cygwin\bin
 set EDITOR=vi
 set VISUAL=vi
 set CYGWIN=codepage:oem tty binmode title
 rxvt -sr -sl 10000 -fg white -bg black -fn fixedsys -fb fixedsys -tn cygwin -e bash --login -i

Mintty is a terminal emulator for Cygwin and MSYS. In Cygwin, it is installed as the default terminal by Cygwin's setup.exe. In MSYS, the mintty package can be installed with the command mingw-get install mintty. Alternatively, binaries for Cygwin 1.7, 1.5 and MSYS can be found on the Minitty downloads page.

Comment: Unless there's an explicit reason not to, I'd always use Mintty. When Cygwin creates its shortcuts, the main Cygwin terminal shortcut uses Mintty for a reason.