# Howto create an alias for Zend Framework to work with Cygwin in Windows with XAMPP

Tags: php, zend-framework, windows-7, cygwin, xampp

I'm using Zend Framework at the office in a Windows7+XAMPP environment; I'm not able to change this even if I want to, so I need to adapt. SO, I naturally installed Cygwin and Console2 in order to work in a more Linux-like environment.
The PHP and MySQL paths are in the environmental variables of Windows, so if I do in CMD this:

```
php --version
PHP 5.4.4 (cli) (built: Jun 13 2012 21:27:06)
```

There is a reponse. If I do the same in my Cygwig environment I also got response, so Cygwin can find the PHP path.
About Zend Framework, I downloaded the zip file and extracted the contents of the ZF bin directory to `C:\xampp\php` (that means zf.sh, zf.bat and zf.php) and all the library folder content to `C:\xampp\php\pear\Zend` so those are in the right path to be used.

In Windows CMD I managed to create something similar to an alias this way:

```
#cmd_aliases.txt
zf=php C:\xampp\php\zf.php $*

#cmd_autorun.cmd
@echo off
cls
doskey /macrofile=C:\Users\hector.ayala\Documents\cmd_aliases.txt

#cmd_autorun_install.cmd
reg add "hkcu\software\microsoft\command processor" /v Autorun /t reg_sz /d C:\cmd_autorun.cmd
```

And now in CMD I can do:

```
>zf show version
Zend Framework Version: 1.11.12
```

...as intended. **HOWEVER** I can't do something similar in CygWin...
I did this in Cygwin:
    $ cd ZendFramework-XX
    $ mv bin/* /usr/local/bin
    $ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/zf.sh
    $ ln -s /usr/local/bin/zf.sh /usr/local/bin/zf

That means I did a symlink to the `zf.sh` in order to launch ZF just with `zf`. However I got this:

```
$ zf show version
Could not open input file: /usr/local/bin/zf.php
```

Then I said, Oh well! Maybe it's ZF problem... My PHP returns me it's version so PHP works, surely any kink of php file will work:

```
$ php simple_test.php
Could not open input file: simple_test.php
```

What the...? Why PHP works but at the same time it doesn't?
Any ideas what can I do to just call Zend Framekork CLI with a simple custom `zf` as I did with CMD?

Comment: Does "not able to change this" include the installation of virtualization solutions? If not, you should take a look at [virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org) or even better [vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com).

Comment: I've used VirtualBox before, I didn't knew about Vagrant, thanks for the tip. BUT here at my office there's some bureaucracy... I'd have already installed Linux or even VirtualBox but sadly they won't let me do it and I don't want to have troubles here, so I need to adapt.. I know it MUST be some way to do it..........

Comment: Btw, there is another console emulator: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/1405560

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found  way!!!!
I didn't knew about [cygpath](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-effectively.html) It's a command line utility for converting between Windows and POSIX paths. Because Windows couldn't understand the path, the `zf.sh` couldn't process it and because of that I could get PHP version, but PHP couldn't comprehend the path to files to work with them, thus the `Could not open input file` error. So all PHP needed was to understand the path.

So reading the help of `cygpath` in the given link, I was able to understand this command and adapt the official `zf.sh` to my needs. So I changed into it the very last line from this:

```
"$PHP_BIN" -d safe_mode=Off -f "$PHP_DIR/zf.php" -- "$@"
```

To this:

```
"$PHP_BIN" -d safe_mode=Off -f "$(cygpath -aw $PHP_DIR/zf.php)" -- "$@"
```

Now it works!

```
$ zf show version
Zend Framework Version: 1.11.12
```

Hopefully someone will find this useful ;)