# how do i get console to notify me when it is finished running a script

Tags: shell, windows-7, console, cmd, console2

I am using nant, but this can apply to any thing, I just want to know if there is a way to set  windows cmd or console2  or some kind of shell to give me a popup or make a noise when it is "finished" (i.e. when it is waiting and the screen says >C:\User\Random_FILE_PATH>_)

I'm using windows 7.

Valentine

sorry, to clarify, I am not running a script that I created, this is just when running anything in the console. I would like it to be that anytime my console is waiting for me it creates a pop up or a noise. This would ideally be some kind of setting

Comment: If you want to give a try to [ConEmu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/1405560) - it provides access to MsgBox and Win7 taskbar progress "from the box".

Answer (score 0):

You may open a message box in the end of your batch file, using WSH with a simple VBScript or JScript. See [Show a popup/message box from a Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774175/how-can-i-open-a-message-box-in-a-windows-batch-file) for an example.

Comment: sorry, to clarify, I am not running a script that I created, this is just when running anything in the console. I would like it to be that anytime my console is waiting for me it creates a pop up or a noise. This would ideally be some kind of setting

Answer (score 0):

```
c:\> my_command & mshta.exe vbscript:Execute("msgbox ""finished"",0,""finished"":close")
```

this here uses conditional execution - when **my_command** is finished the mshta.exe will be executed with arguments in the brackets.As the parameter passing here is not so easy the string given to msgbox will not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a beep to your prompt:

```
set prompt=%prompt%^G
```

Don't type `^G`. To get it, keep your alt-key pressed while entering `0` `0` `7` on your numeric keyboard.