# Console2 settings not getting saved between sessions

Tags: windows, powershell, console2

I had a nice Console2 setup going until i screwed with the settings and it messed my entire setup. I unzipped and copied the original files over the existing install and deleted the console.xml file in the User settings dir (User/AppData/Roaming/Console/console.xml). No matter what combination I try, my transparency setting does not get saved between sessions. In fact, in the same session if I go back to the settings modal, the Transparency is set back to None. The weird thing is, my settings on the Appearance tab all get saved just fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to delete my settings file under AppData/Roaming and deleted the entire Console2 folder. I re-downloaded it and re-installed it. I have no idea why it did not work when i just deleted the settings file in my AppData directory.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried multiple times changing my settings and it would last for a single session but be gone next time I opened the console. It was a simple fix. When you open the preferences check the box in the bottom left hand corner that reads **"Save settings to user directory"** this will cause settings to be saved between sessions.

Comment: This is the definitive answer IMO

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to change transparency manually, look at your xml file and change `active_alpha` & `inactive_alpha` values of `<transparency>` key. Value of `255` means "Opaque".

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <settings>
     <appearance>
       ...
       <transparency type="1" active_alpha="204" inactive_alpha="169" r="0" g="0" b="0"/>
     </appearance>
     ...
   </settings>
   ```
2. Try updated version, [ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console) fork is currenty supported.
3. Try another terminal - [ConEmu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/1405560) (I'm the author). It is maintened and full of features.

Comment: This did not help either.

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. It might a problem to do with your other settings as well. See if you can spot any discrepancies between your and my Console2 settings:

In the xml file showing my current transparency readings under appearance are:

```
<transparency b="0" g="0" r="0" inactive_alpha="215" active_alpha="215" type="1"/>
```

Screenshot: http://puu.sh/67DgL.png

[image: Appearance]

[image: More...]

[image: Behavior] [image: tabs background]

Comment: My settings look exactly the same. It almost feels like the settings file is hosed.

Comment: @mithun_daa Sorry that I couldn't help. I'm glad you fixed your issue, might have been missing some folder components. cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and, after trying a number of different things, discovered that my user no longer had write permissions to the "console.xml" file in the same directory as the Console2 executable.

No idea what caused that to happen, but fixing the permissions on that file allowed me to save my Console2 settings again.